# Recursive function not appending numbers

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I have been trying to figure out why my recursive function is not returning any numbers. `vi` is `vector<int>` and `x` in the original function call is empty. Everything else is irrelevant (works correctly).  What should be happening is `c` is pushed back into `x` and `x` is returned. The function works fine if have it return nothing and push `c`s into a global vector.

```
vi generate(const vvi &paths, int index, int start, int end_, int c, vi x)
{
    if (start == end_)
    {
        x.push_back(c);
        return x;
    }



    for(auto path : paths)
    {
        if(path[0] == start)
        {
            x = generate(paths, index, path[1], end_, path[index] + c, x);
        }

    }
    return x;

}
```

Example:

`paths` is a vector of vector of ints. Here is the structure visualized

```
{{1, 2, 1, 0},
 {2, 3, 1, 0},
 {1, 3, 1, 0}}
```

Called with `generate(paths, 2, 1, 3, 0, x)`. The start and end are 1 and 3. C starts at 0. x is an empty vector of ints.

Expected (to clarify, something not empty, order doesn't matter):

```
{1, 2}
```

First number from path 1 to 3, second number from path 1 to 2 and path 2 to 3.

Comment: Please provide an example call with expected output.

Comment: Your edit does not constitute an example call with expected output.

Comment: Your expected output depends entirely on the function's input, which you are not sharing.

Comment: The actual output is not important, just that the push_back is working. I will edit the post for the input

Comment: @qwr Ok, now that we have an example... you want `{1,2}` but it produces `{2,1}`... is the issue just that it's backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `x` by value. Try passing it by reference instead: `vi &x`. You also have bug(s) in your program. If `start` is not equal to `end_` you do not record the "move".

Comment: Shouldn't value and reference return the same thing?

Comment: Hmmmm, yes, but still that's a lot of copying. You should drop the return value and just use the reference.

Comment: I have found the issue. I was calling `generate` but not saving the vector. That is why passing by reference worked.